# Remove columns from dataframe based on month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have df with two columns - 'PORTFOLIO' and 'DATE'(datetime.date(2018, 9, 19)) format.
I'm trying to remove the rows with current month and last month i.e., if current month is `March`, 'Jan' and 'Feb' data should be removed.
Similary if current month is `Feb 2020`, 'Jan 2020' and 'Dec 2019' data should be removed.
Example: df

```
                          PORTFOLIO  DATE
                        0   A       2018-09-19
                        1   B       2018-03-09
                        2   C       2019-03-09
                        3   D       2020-01-02
                        4   E       2020-01-17
                        5   F       2020-02-09
                        6   G       2020-03-15
                        7   H       2019-10-05
                        8   I       2018-03-09
                        9   J       2020-01-21
                        10  K       2019-03-08
                        11  L       2019-02-12
                        12  M       2020-03-01
                        13  N       2020-02-16
```

My resultant df:

```
                          PORTFOLIO  DATE
                        0   A       2018-09-19
                        1   B       2018-03-09
                        2   C       2019-03-09
                        3   D       2020-01-02
                        4   E       2020-01-17
                        5   H       2019-10-05
                        6   I       2018-03-09
                        7   J       2020-01-21
                        8   K       2019-03-08
                        9   L       2019-02-12
```

Comment: i think u should change the heading... misleading, since u r removing rows, not columns. pedantic i know but it is what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need working with month periods created by [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) for today `period`, column values are converted similar by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and tested previous 2 periods by subtract 1 and 2 in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), so possible filter by inverted mask with `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

now = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m')
print (now)
2020-03

df = df[~df['DATE'].dt.to_period('m').isin([now, now-1])]
```

Similar solution if need some range with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), by default inclusive, so also filter `now-1` and `now` values:

```
df = df[~df['DATE'].dt.to_period('m').between(now-1, now)]
print (df)
   PORTFOLIO       DATE
0          A 2018-09-19
1          B 2018-03-09
2          C 2019-03-09
3          D 2020-01-02
4          E 2020-01-17
7          H 2019-10-05
8          I 2018-03-09
9          J 2020-01-21
10         K 2019-03-08
11         L 2019-02-12
```

Comment: Current month data also should be excluded. G and M dates are from current month